# Robot doesnt detect web element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, robotframework

[image]I have unique identifier for a web element but Robot is not able to identify its path(may be I am building the path wrong).

`#app-header-stats-rogue div span.stat_value` this is unique identifier
`id=app-header-stats-rogue`
I also tried locating as `css=.app-header-stats-rogue div span.stat_value`
I also tried building xpath `//*[@id="app-header-stats-rogue"]/div/span[2]` that does not work either.

HTML-`<a id="app-header-stats-rogue" href="/rogues" class="stats-link"><p class="header_name">ROGUE</p><div><span class="navIcoFirst icon_no app-header-stats-error "></span><span class="stat_value headerLabel">0</span></div></a>`

FAIL : Element with locator 'css=.app-header-stats-rogue div span.stat_value' not found

Comment: Add the relevant html, w/o it it's impossible to spot errors in the locator.

Comment: I have added the screen shot.

Comment: no one will write html for you from image unless you provide, its always better to attach html instead screenshot

Comment: `<a id="app-header-stats-rogue" href="/rogues" class="stats-link"><p class="header_name">ROGUE</p><div><span class="navIcoFirst icon_no app-header-stats-error "></span><span class="stat_value headerLabel">0</span></div></a>`

Comment: meanwhile you can try `//a[@class='stats-link']/div/span[2]` xpath

Comment: Its not unique, there are other elements with the same xpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[@id="app-header-stats-rogue"]/div/span[2]
```

or

```
//a[@href="/rogues"]/div/span[2]
```

should do.